# Getting same value of test statistics when using data with different variabilities

Tags: r

What I intending to do   is generating data from two samples with different variations and calculating the test statistics.  I was expecting to get two  different values of my test Statistics.

I run the same code with minor change in  getting the data for
new2_samples  as I replaced the term   sqrt(200)*new1_samples by sqrt(800)*new1_samples to increase the variability of the generated data
I was  expecting different value of D1 but I got exactly the same value.
I could not identify what went wrong. Please advise.

Here is the R code I used , I only replicate it twice to be able to examine the output.

```
library(MASS)
set.seed(123)
# generate first sample
sample1 = replicate(2, rnorm(10,0,1), simplify=FALSE)
set.seed(456)
sample2 = replicate(2, rnorm(10,0,1), simplify=FALSE)

set.seed(789)
sample3 = replicate(2, rnorm(10,0,1), simplify=FALSE)
set.seed(101)
sample4 = replicate(2, rnorm(10,0,1), simplify=FALSE)
# express the data in matrix format
for (i in 1:2) {  
  sample1R = matrix(sample1[[i]], nrow=10, ncol=1)
  sample2R = matrix(sample2[[i]], nrow=10, ncol=1)
  
  # get the first set of data  
  
  sum_matrix = sample1R + sample2R
  new1_samples <- sqrt(0.5)* sum_matrix
  
  # set the mean to 100 and add it to the data
  mean_R=100
  # use constant c = sqrt(200 ) to reflect variation  of the data
  new2_samples<- sqrt(200)*new1_samples + mean_R
  
  #generate  second data  set
  sample1T = matrix(sample3[[i]], nrow=10, ncol=1)
  sample2T = matrix(sample4[[i]], nrow=10, ncol=1)
  
  
  Tsum_matrix = sample1T + sample2T
  
  Tnew1_samples <- sqrt(0.5)* Tsum_matrix
  
  # I will not multiply this data set with any constant to make sure it does not have same variabilities as the first data set  
  mean_T=100
   Tnew2_samples<- Tnew1_samples + mean_T
  
  # Calculate the standard deviation for each of the two data set 
  sd_T <- sd(Tnew2_samples)
  sd_R <- sd(new2_samples)
  
  
  # up_new2_row1 <- new2_samples[1] 
  
  up_new2_row1 <- new2_samples[1] + 5*sd_R
  
  up_Tnew2_row1 <- Tnew2_samples[1]
  #combine the two data sets  
  up_firstrow= cbind(up_new2_row1[],up_Tnew2_row1[]  )
  #combine  both full  columns 
  up_matrix= cbind(new2_samples,Tnew2_samples )
  
  # Update the up_samples matrix
  
  up_samples <- rbind(up_firstrow[],up_matrix[-1, ]  )
  
  
  # calculating my test stat
  
  
  H= up_samples
  
  mean_data1= mean(H[,1] )
  
  mean_data2= mean(H[,2] )
  
  
  mean_matrix=matrix( c(mean_data1, mean_data2  ), nrow=1, ncol=2, byrow=TRUE)
  
  
  
  residu1= H[1,]- mean_matrix
  cov_matrix= cov(H)
  
  n=10  
  s= (n-1)*cov(H)
  
  
  s_inverse<- solve(s)
  
  
  
  residu1_prime= t(residu1)
  # the test stat
  
  D1= residu1 %*% s_inverse %*% residu1_prime
  
  T_1= ((n-2)*D1)/((( n-1)/n)-D1 )
  
  
  cat("Simulation", i, ":\n")
  
  print("up_samples")
  
  print(up_samples)
  
  print(" D1")
  
  print( D1)
  print(" T_1")
  
  print( T_1)
}
```

Comment: Hi Amal! Have you ever used the R debugger before? It's my first port of call when I run into strange outputs like this

Comment: Also why are you setting the seed multiple times? I stand to be corrected, but I believe it only needs to be set once